# Downcasting Objects when retrieving them from a Collection

Tags: java

I am currently programming a game, using a variant of a self written component based entity engine.
As I define my entities and the components they have, i figured to use the following idea to adress them properly for the rest of the system to use:

```
class Entity {

...
```

Used to identify different components:

```
enum ComponentID() {
    BODY,
    GRAPHICS,
    INVENTORY;
}
...
```

Should hold all components:

```
EnumMap<ComponentID, ModelComponent> components = new EnumMap<>(ComponentID.class);
}
```

First, we have a super class called ModelComponent and some different concrete subclasses like Body, Graphics, AI and so on that extend ModelComponent.

The components EnumMap should hold references to all ModelComponents an entity has.
The problem arises when I want to ask the system for a specific component. If I want to get the body component for example because the physics class wants to calculate some collisions, I would write code like:

```
public Body getBody() {
    return (Body) components.get(ComponentID.BODY);
}
```

The cast is needed because somewhere in my game, say if i want to access the velocity of an entity, I would invoke:

```
Vector2 velocity = entity.getBody().getVelocity();
```

However, getVelocity() is a method that is only defined in the concrete sublass Body.

My question is: Is this a proper usage of downcasting to a subclass? I don't know, whether the down cast can be avoided by better design, because obviously a Graphics component will do completely different stuff than lets say the Body component, so both of them will have completly different methods.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention the following details that may be important to answer this question:

1) Of course there are more concrete subclasses of Entity like Player, Enemy, Trigger etc. and they all should have a **different** combination of ModelComponents.
The player does not need an AI component where as an enemy does.

2) My goals with this refactor was to get rid of the fields

```
Body body;
Graphics graphics;
Inventory inventory;
Ai ai;
```

because every entity instantiated in my game would have all of those fields.
The enummap would have eliminated this problem, as I would replace all getXXX() methods with the following line of code:

```
public ModelComponent get(ComponentID id) {
return components.get(id);

}
```

Comment: You only have 3 enum constants. Why not just define them as 3 fields with their specific type?

Comment: You may want to consider something like Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#classtoinstancemap).

Comment: @Jorn_Vernee That is a brilliant question. Actually, that's how the current code looks like.  I attempted this refactor to maybe make the code more flexible for a larger amount of different components.

Comment: But you still have specific methods to get values from the enum set, like `getBody`. So why the 'flexibility'?

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp, because I wanted to get rid of all specific getters and replace them with one get(ComponentID id) method. But I don't know if it is really worth it yet.

Comment: Why not have the methods in the `enum` constants?

Comment: @LewBloch, could you give an example? Maybe I am missing knowledge of a common feature.

Comment: Like this:

    enum ComponentID {
      BODY(new Body()),
      GRAPHICS(new Graphics()),
      INVENTORY(new Inventory());

      final Component component;
      ComponentID(Component compon) {this.component = compon;}
      public Component getComponent() {
        return component;
      }
    }

Comment: @LewBloch you do realize everyone will get the same instance of the object, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No. Because you're adding implicit logic. The downcast works in this case, because you know it's correct, because in code you will set the right objects. But the compiler can't check this, and possible other developers neither. So someone else could change the code and the compiler won't complain and only at run time a class cast exception will be thrown.